# How can we find out the number of incoming and outgoing links on a portal?

Tags: ingress

It's very hard to track the outgoing links from a portal whilst planning fields, especially if you didn't plan for that specific portal to be an anchor at the time. Is there a way to find out the total number of outgoing links from a portal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The links do have a flow animation on them which represents their direction. The only problem with the animation is, that it's in the opposite direction.

An incoming link is represented with a flow going out of the portal, and an outgoing link is represented with a flow coming to the portal.

You only have to zoom to the portal and count the links which have an incoming flow animation.